# When click on Delete button redirect me to Update page in PHP

Tags: php, e-commerce

```
 echo "<a href='categories.php?do=Edit&catid=" . $cat['ID'] ."' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit </a>";
                echo "<a href='categories.php?do=Delete&catid=" . $cat['ID'] . "' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger confirm'><i class='fa fa-close'></i> Delete </a>";
```

When i click on Delete button, it open Update page not Delete Page
Although href is :categories.php?do=Delete&catid=

code of delete page is :

```
//Delete Member Page
echo "<h1 class='text-center'>Delete Category</h1>";
echo "<div class='container'>";

$catid = isset($_GET['catid']) && is_numeric($_GET['catid']) ? intval ($_GET['catid']) : 0;

$check = checkItem('ID', 'cato', $catid);


  if($check > 0 ) {

    $stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM cato WHERE ID = :zid");

    $stmt->bindParam(":zid", $catid);

    $stmt->execute();

    $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Done</div>";

    redirectHome($theMsg);

  }else {

    $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Sorry You Cannot Delete It</div>";

    redirectHome($theMsg);
  }

  echo "</div>";
```

Comment: based on your link shown in code. it will always `categories.php`.

Comment: Where is `redirectHome`?

Comment: redirectHome is function to get back page or redirect to home.

Comment: My problem is when i open delete page i found update page

Comment: And when i click on delete button nothing happen to category , it's mean button doesn't work

Comment: Please show code for categories.php